# How to properly use refreshListenable and redirect property in GoRouter

Tags: flutter, riverpod, flutter-go-router

In my Flutter project, I'm trying to check at every request if the response from the back-end returns an invalid token to then logout the user and redirect them to the login page again.

To check if the token is invalid I am using a provider to replace the original http client, and instead use my client with the only difference of checking for the invalid token before returning the response, the main part where I am having issues is as follows :

```dart
final response = await http.Response.fromStream(await request.send());

    if (response.statusCode == 401 ||
        response.body.contains("FST_JWT_AUTHORIZATION_TOKEN_INVALID")) {
      getLogout(_ref.read(boxProvider));
      _ref.watch(invalidTokenProvider.notifier).toggle(true);
    }

    return response;
```

From this, it works fine and once it detects the invalid token it detects this and does the logout function which clears the token, my problem is the redirect method. I am trying to use a ChangeNotifierProvider to change the simple boolean value if the token is invalid or not. This is my provider :

```dart
final invalidTokenProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<TokenNotifier>((ref) => TokenNotifier());

class TokenNotifier extends ChangeNotifier {
  bool invalidToken = false;

  void toggle(bool value) {
    invalidToken = value;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

And then just simply using it on my GoRouter :

```dart
GoRouter(
    routes: $appRoutes,
    initialLocation: '/',
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    refreshListenable: ref.watch(invalidTokenProvider.notifier),
    redirect: (context, state) {
      if (ref.read(invalidTokenProvider).invalidToken) {
        return '/';
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    },
  );
```

My logic would be, as soon as the value in the provider changes, the listenable detects this change and checks for the redirect, which would then redirect to SplashScreen that would then continue the normal flow of logging in.
My problem is that it simply ignores the toggle to true and does not refresh, and actually seems to not even check the value of the provider considering even when I navigate to other pages it doesn't redirect. So I think I am having both a problem with the Listenable and the Redirect property and would be very thankful for any sort of input to change this.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be watching the Provider rather than the Notifier
Try changing the refreshListenable to

```dart
refreshListenable: ref.watch(invalidTokenProvider),
```

Riverpod Docs on Notifiers
https://pub.dev/documentation/riverpod/latest/riverpod/Notifier-class.html